# Rails defining task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

i've got several tasks like this:

```
desc "Generate and send something"
 task(:generate_something => :environment) do
```

Those were situtated in lib/tasks

Is there any possibility to don't set up the environment? I want that the task find out by it selve which environment is active at the moment?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply test the `Rails.env` variable as in the app itself:

```
desc "Test task"
task :blaff do
  puts Rails.env
  puts Rails.env.production?
end
```

Now you can run this in any environment you want:

```
% rake blaff 
development
false

% RAILS_ENV=production rake blaff
production
true

% RAILS_ENV=test rake blaff
test
false
```

Comment: do I need `|t|` and when why? ... I don't want totest it the action should take data from the specified database. The rails app runs in test and so the task should take the data from the test database...

Comment: No, sorry, you don't need `|t|` unless you want any data from the task itself. Old habit. Will update the answer.

Comment: when I do this: `task :blaff do` it dosn't matter which environment is started? it works automatically für dev, test, production?